# POST call with AJAX and MAP API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, post

I have done my research, but I haven't found a example using `AJAX`, `REST` `POST` with a `register key` from `MAP API` (the examples I found don't have the key). For example, I want to use a SEARCHALL function on a `MAP API`, by using `AJAX` to call for it. I have the URL and a register key.
I'm new to Visual Studio, so I'm struggling as where to put the function call and the key, as well as writing the POST function itself. It would be great if you can provide an example, or a link/ tutorial where I can see the code in action.

Comment: what kind of maps,did you read the documentation?

Comment: It's similar to google map. The doc's kinda lacking (or maybe it's just me). It showed a REST request message **+ Address:** http:// **+ Method:** POST **+ Http Headers:** - Key: RegisterKey Value: < YourRegisterKey > - Key: Content-Type Value: application/Rest **+ Content:**

Comment: for example the autosuggest search: for JSON `{ "Keyword":"String content" }` It doesnt make sense much to me how I should go about it